# Good way to have multiple URLs to same site and serve slightly different content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Take 2 websites :

```
website1.com

website2.com
```

Both owned by the same company, lets say they're swimming pools in different towns.

Both domains both point to the same server, which is `website1.com`. The server has one page on it.

PHP and JavaScript are available.

> What the client wants : if someone goes to `website1.com`, the top
>   picture should be of the water slides. If someone goes to
>   `website2.com`, the top picture should be of the giant turtle.

My method so far :

Since `website2.com` is a redirect, I make it redirect to `website1.com?source=2`.

1) I use javascript to look at the URL.

2) If source is in it, then I place a cookie `source=2`.

3) Then on every page, I look at the cookies.

4) If there is a cookie with `source=2`, then a variable is set in javascript, like `poolLocation=2`. Default value is `poolLocation=1`.

5) Then, wherever the content might be location specific, like in our top picture, I use javascript to test what `poolLocation` is with an if/else.

```
//$(function() {...
if(poolLocation === 2) {
    $('#variableImage1').attr('src', 'img2.png');
} else {
    $('#variableImage1').attr('src', 'img1.png');
}

<img id='variableImage1' />
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you inspect `window.location.href` for the specific domain? Like `if (window.location.href.indexOf('website1.com') !== -1) {`

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: @crush looks like the domain will be the same in both cases (2 is a redirect)

Comment: Missed that part. Why redirect if the sites are supposed to have different identities?

Comment: why don't you do this in the server code? Not hard to have the same code base run on multiple sites and have variations in output based on whichever host is serving it

Comment: In continuation of my last comment, you can point two host records to the same web application - in case that is the reason you are redirecting.

Comment: Insead of cookies, and since PHP is available, you might make use of sessions!

Comment: @crush slightly different identities. I could just maintain the 2 domains separately, but 99% of the site is the same.

Comment: @jason Well, what I mean is the two different domains would point to the same site's code.

Answer (score 0):

If both domains are actually being allowed to hit the PHP code (there's no redirect happening in an .htaccess file), I would recommend checking `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` for the domain and switching the value of some PHP variables (e.g. an image `$src` variable) before the code ever hits the front end. That would be my approach.

Just be careful to allow the user to stay on the domain they came from in this case - don't redirect them to any particular domain, and use relative URL paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using apache, you could add a ServerAlias directive like `ServerAlias website2.com` in the config file of the website1.com, that way people accessing from website2.com will see the same content, later using PHP you could know which domain is people accessing from and therefor filter part of the content.

i.e.

```
<img class="main-image" src="images/<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'website1.com' ? 'water-slides.jpg' : 'giant-turtle.jpg' ?>"/>
```

or, if you prefer doing it on JS:

```
<script>
var domain = '<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>';
$(document).on('ready',function() {
    $('.main-image').attr('src','images/'+(domain == 'website1.com' ? 'water-slides.jpg' : 'giant-turtle.jpg')');
});
</script>
```